# Storing results of phpcs fixer into a file

Tags: php, terminal, phpcs

Is there any option to store the output of the phpcs fixer results into a file ?

I tried the below

```
phpcs --standard='Symfony' -a 'path' --report-file='~/Users/uname/Desktop/PHPcs'
```

But it gives an error:

> ERROR: The specified report file path
>   "~/Users/uname/Desktop/PHPcs" points to a non-existent directory

Run "`phpcs --help`" for usage information

Comment: Try to use full path, for example : `C:\Users\uname\Desktop\PHPcs` the windows way

Comment: Did you tried to specify full path to directory?Are you sure that this directory exists?

Comment: try to remove the quotes, see if that helps with shell expansion

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko Yes .

Comment: try to replace "/" by "\"

Comment: Also you can try to move PHPcs folder to C:/ folder

Comment: @DmitriyButeiko this removed the error.But still the file shows as zero bytes and i have changed the permission of the file to read write all everyone.

Comment: Try to create the directory first, as well as playing with different formats and/or provoque an error, in order to have some output.

Example: `mkdir -p ~/Users/uname/Desktop/PHPcs && phpcs --standard='Symfony' -a 'path' --report=junit  --report-file='~/Users/uname/Desktop/PHPcs/junit.xml'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok got the issue sorted.

When you do the below

```
phpcs --standard='Symfony' -a app/path --report="~\Users\uname\Desktop\PHPcs\PHPGOG.txt"
```

You dont have to create your own folder

PHPCS fixer will generate the report in the same path [at the place of your code ] for which you are running the phpcs fixer.

Comment: You can also use common bash command for such use cases: `phpcs ... > output.txt`

Comment: `--report-file="~\Users\uname\Desktop\PHPcs\PHPGOG.txt" ? That worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Nice question! As Tomáš Votruba said using **>** can do the trick for you.

Example of the command

```
phpcs [your command] > log.txt
```

The file will get created in the directory you are while running the command.